# SQL - Comparing Data From One Table

Tags: sql

I'm a bit new to PL/SQL and I'm not sure what the best approach is to compare the data from the same table.

So there is a table that stores User Settings, but not all users have the same settings.  It's best I show it in a snippet of an example:

```
User   Setting   Value        
----   -------   -----
Carol  Timezone  GMT
Carol  PageSize  300
Greg   Timezone  EST
Greg   PageSize  300
Greg   Duration  10 
Bill   PageSize  250
Bill   Duration  20
Fred   Timezone  30
...    ...       ...
```

Let's say there are thousands of users.  I want to somehow compare the values between Carol, Greg, and Bill but do not want to include of the others (Fred, etc).

Is it possible to have the table look something like this?

```
Setting   Carol   Greg    Bill
-------   -----   -----   ----
Timezone  GMT     EST     (null)
PageSize  300     300     250
Duration  (null)  10      20
```

Comment: You mention pl/slq, you should add the oracle tag. And oracle can do pivots. Look here http://sql-plsql-de.blogspot.de/2007/08/kreuztabellen-in-oracle11g-sql-pivot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select setting,
       max(case when user = 'Carol' then value else null end) as Carol,
       max(case when user = 'Greg' then value else null end) as Greg,
       max(case when user = 'Bill' then value else null end) as Bill
from your_table
WHERE user IN ('Carol','Greg','Bill')
group by setting
```

Comment: If there are thousands of users might it benefit performance to also include a where statement? WHERE user IN ('Carol','Greg','Bill')  I know that depends on other factors too but just a thought.